setTimeout - change duration after click
I have function setTimeout in JS:
Interval = 20000;

timer = setTimeout(function loop(){ 
   //do something
   timer = setTimeout(loop, Interval);                  
}, 1);

$("#next_button").click(function(e) {                           
   Interval = 1;
}); 

Why shortening intervel after click doesn't work

x = 10; console.log(x); x = 20; also doesn't change what is printed. JS is pass-by-value.

As @VLAZ wrote move $("#next._button).click ...  just after Interval = 20000

@Mehdi that won't change anything. Unless a user can trigger the click handler in the less than millisecond it'd take between assigning a value to Interval to attaching the click handler. And they can't because clicking is async anyway and the code will run to completion before executing any of the handlers. I don't see where I've claimed otherwise.

@VLAZ you are absolutely right don't know how I wrote that.

So, how can I resolve this problem? Mayby an example please


Cancel the old one 2. Start a new one.


Technically it works, but what the code is not doing is cancelling the previous setTimeout call and start a new one, so it will be called at some point


let intervalDuration = 2000

const loop = () => {
  console.log(`Interval Value:`, intervalDuration)

  timeoutId = setTimeout(loop, intervalDuration)
}

let timeoutId = setTimeout(loop, intervalDuration)

const button = document.querySelector('.button')

button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  intervalDuration = 500
  clearTimeout(timeoutId)

  loop()
})
<button class="button">Click Me</button>



